# How to retrieve the value in the input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, var

I'm trying to retrieve the value in the input, however I'm not too sure how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
<body onload="displayMessage()">
  <h1> JavaScript Arrays</h1>
  <br>
  <form name="hey">
    Enter value:
    <br>
    <input type="" name="firstname" value="">
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayMessage()">Add to list</button>
  </form>

  <p></p>

  <p id="pie"></p>

  <br>

  <p id="beef"></p>

</body>
```

Comment: try this: var userInput = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `+` sign after `"The user entered: "`, and I assume you want to push `userInput` instead of `"Arrays"` into the array.

I also used `.insertAdjacentHTML()` so that you didn't overwrite the original `.innerHTML` setting. I shortened the code as well by storing the `pie` element in a variable.

```js
var Arrays = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Smart phone", "Motherboard", "Hard drive"];
document.getElementById("beef").innerHTML = Arrays;


function displayMessage() {
  var userInput = document.hey.firstname.value; 
  var pie = document.getElementById("pie");

  // ----------------------------------v
  pie.innerHTML = "The user entered: " + userInput + "<br>";

  Arrays.push(userInput); // <------------ push the new item

  // Prevent overwrite--v
  pie.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", Arrays);
}
```

```html
<h1> JavaScript Arrays</h1>
<br>
<form name="hey">
  Enter value:
  <br>
  <input type="" name="firstname" value="">
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="displayMessage()">Add to list</button>
</form>

<p></p>

<p id="pie"></p>

<br>

<p id="beef"></p>
```

The rest was correct.

---

In addition though, It's a good idea to use lowercase words for variable names. This is the common JavaScript convention used.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding userInput to the arrays, you are simply adding a static text 'Arrays' to the array

```
function displayMessage() {
  var userInput = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("pie").innerHTML = "The user entered: " + userInput + "<br>";
  Arrays.push( userInput );
  document.getElementById("pie").innerHTML = Arrays.join( "," );
}
```

and you also missed the concatenation operator `+` before `userInput` as well

Answer (score 0):

- you need a `+` here `user entered: " + userInput`
- `Arrays.push(userInput);`
- `document.getElementById("beef").innerHTML = Arrays;`
- `userInput && Arrays.push(userInput);` to prevent empty inserts

```js
var Arrays = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Smart phone", "Motherboard", "Hard drive"];
document.getElementById("beef").innerHTML = Arrays;


function displayMessage() {
  var userInput = document.hey.firstname.value;
  userInput && Arrays.push(userInput);
  document.getElementById("pie").innerHTML = ("The user entered: " + userInput + "<br>");
  document.getElementById("beef").innerHTML = Arrays;
}
```

```html
<body onload="displayMessage()">
  <h1> JavaScript Arrays</h1>
  <form name="hey">
    Enter value: <input type="" name="firstname" value=""> <button type="button" onclick="displayMessage()">Add to list</button>
  </form>
  <p id="pie"></p>
  <p id="beef"></p>
```